# Azure DataFactory find output structure of activity block without Debugging

Tags: azure-data-factory

Currently, in order to use the various data-manipulation blocks of Azure DataFactory (v2) I need to run the pipeline in the Debugger, and view the actual outputs, in order findout what the JSON structure of their outputs is.

*Some* of the Activities have sample outputs documented in MSDN (e.g. [`Get Metadata` Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity#sample-output)) but others don't (e.g. [`Filter` Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-filter-activity)).

The Author 'IDE' doesn't have any autocomplete :(

So is there any way that I could have known that I wanted the `.Values` property of the filter output, without having to *actually execute* the pipeline up to that point?

Comment: Can you tell that I've just picked up ADF for the first time :) other beginner questions also recently posted under the same tag.

Comment: What it outputs is actually the value of 'items' in the settings of filter activity. Therefore, if you don't want to get it through debug, you can only infer the value of Values based on the logic of the entire pipeline. Can this answered your question?

Comment: @Brondahl All the actives are running in the pipeline. We must first run(debug) the pipeline, then the actives can run. There is no way that you get the output of the actives without executing the pipeline.

Comment: No, obviously not the *actual* runtime values! The **JSON structure** of the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the actives are running in the pipeline. We must first run(debug) the pipeline, then the actives can run.

There is no way that you get the output of the actives without executing the pipeline.

Ref: [Pipelines and activities in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipelines-activities).

Comment: :( Yeah, that's what I had concluded too. That sucks :(